# Is it possible to have a button next to the filter bar for listview?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a listview and it is defined with data-filter='true' which will show the filter bar.

In my listview, each item has a class which has value either "Buy", "Pick" or "Normal".

I would like to have a means to filter the list based on this class name. To do that, I was thinking of having a button next to the filter bar so that the user can use it to toggle the class name to filter the list accordingly.

So, the basic question is -- Is it possible to add a button next to the filter bar?

Other alternative I have is to add button to the header which clutters up the header because I got 2 other buttons there already.

Any help is most appreciated.